# Category based on post id

Tags: wp-query, array

I have the following:

```
$custom_loop = new WP_Query( array('category_name'=>$category, 'meta_key'=>'name', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=>'-1'));
```

How can I tell it that if `$post->ID == 1` then `$category == 'first'` and if `$post->ID == 2` then `$category == 'second'`

I suppose it should be an array of some sort, but I just can't figure out what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Query` itself can't do that logic internally but you can easily create the query dynamically.

```
$args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'name', 
  'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

if ($post->ID == 1) {
  $args['category_name'] = 'first';
} elseif ($post->ID == 2) {
  $args['category_name'] = 'second';
}

$custom_loop = new WP_Query($args);
```